# Every blue moon my computer's time is slow, i.e. a second takes almost a minute to pass

Tags: hardware-failure, time

So, here's the thing, I am absolutely lost what could be the problem here. Let me walk you through the symptoms my computer is showing, and the steps I tried to fix and/or identify the root of the problem. I'll also add a bit of background info about my setup first.

**Background information**

- Self-built computer:

  - Mainboard: ASUS Maximus VII Ranger
  - Processor: Intel Core i7-4770S
  - Graphics Card: Palit GeForce GTX 1070 JetStream
  - Memory: 32GB
  - Hard drives: 4 SSD drives
  - OS: Windows 10
- Computer runs 24/7.
- Computer is about 3 years old, graphics card is a bit younger, but I don't have the exact buying dates at hand right now.

**Symptoms**

- Every blue moon when I try to logon in the morning, the Windows lock screen shows the wrong time. This morning at 9:00 it showed 5:14.
- When I press a key (mouse or keyboard), it takes several minutes for the password prompt to appear.
- I can type my password and login immediately! The visual fade-in effect is just what's slow.
- On the desktop anything that is instant (typing in a text editor, drawing a pixel in paint) happens instantly and without problem.
- Anything that uses a time-delay on purpose (fade-in effects, cursor flashing in a text editor, countdowns...) is super slow.
- Opening the clock shows that one second takes almost a minute to pass.
- The computer isn't overheated.
- The processor is at 0%.
- Memory is fine.
- The time is just slowed down.
- When I reboot, the effect doesn't immediately go away.

  - Boot delays take forever.
  - Time in BIOS is as slow as under Windows.
- The effect disappears without notice after rebooting several times. I then have to resynch the computer time, but otherwise the computer doesn't show any symptoms afterwards.
- The effect then reappears seemingly randomly after a few weeks.

**What I tried**

- Resetting the CMOS.
- Replacing the CMOS battery.
- Flashing the BIOS/Firmware.
- Running diagnostics on memory and CPU.
- Completely unplugging the computer from power for several hours.
- Booting directly into BIOS, without accessing hard drives, to see if Windows is causing the effect. (The effect persists.)
- Go to a computer repair company, but leave immediately after they tried to explain that the slow fade-in of the login screen is due to individual pixels being loaded from a fragmented harddrive.

It's super hard to debug this, as the problem only rarely happens, and while it happens any debugging tools that use time delays (countdowns, fade-in effects for their windows etc.) take forever to use. Also searching for this problem online is like looking for a needle in a haystack, as everything that pops up is about performance issues.

**Again, performance is not the issue. Time itself is slow, otherwise the computer is fine.**

What could be the cause of this? I fear this is unsolvable and I just have to replace the mainboard.

*P.S. I have no idea what to tag this question with. Please feel free to edit my tags. Thanks!*

**Update**

So, today the problem occured again (hence my motivation to post this question):

- I unplugged the computer before going to work.
- During lunch break I went home and tried turning the computer on, but the problem persisted.
- I tried multiple restarts, to no avail.
- I unplugged the computer again and went back to work.
- After coming back home from work in the evening, I tried again, no luck.
- I then removed the graphics card and plugged the monitor into the onboard HDMI slot, computer booted immediately, time speed was back to normal.
- I shut down the computer and plugged the graphics card back in, since then the problem didn't occur anymore.
- I ran some stress tests with OCCT and IntelProcessor Diagnostics Tool, everything looks perfectly fine.

Was this my graphics card? Was this coincidence? I don't know :(

Comment: *"they tried to explain that the slow fade-in of the login screen is due to individual pixels being loaded from a fragmented harddrive"* lamest explanation ever indeed.

Comment: It might be some failure of an electronical component on the motherboard. Hard to give clues without testing electronically your motherboard. 
Is replacing the motherboard, at least temporarily for testing purpose, an option for you? Less likely, maybe a graphic card and/or proc failure.

Comment: What causes the real-time clock to run at normal speed again? Does a total removal of power (including the mains lead) for at least 30 seconds fix it?

Comment: also, how old is the computer ?

Comment: As Pacopaco said, this is most likely a failure of a motherboard component, likely the RTC chip... Years ago this was a unique, even replaceable, module on the board, but modern computers integrate it into other stuff and it usually is not replaceable. The most likely case here is the motherboard is failing.

Comment: @AFH I tried removing power completely for several hours with no avail.

Comment: @Pacopaco About 3 years.

Comment: Replacing the motherboard temporarily is difficult, as the problem occurs so rarely, it won't actually be temporarily.

Comment: Sounds like a HPET issue. Talk to your mobo manufacturer.

Comment: And when is normal operation restored?

Comment: @AFH There is no pattern I can detect. _"The effect disappears without notice after rebooting several times."_

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: I concur with @Ignacio - have you updated the BIOS? Have you tried a fresh install of Windows? (possibly on another hard disk)

Comment: @Attie _"have you updated the BIOS"_ Yes, third point in the _"What I tried"_ list in my question. _"Have you tried a fresh install of Windows?"_ I **really** doubt this has anything to do with Windows or hard disks, considering the effect is visible in BIOS and well before Windows is being loaded or any hard drive is being accessed.

Comment: Oh yes, apologies... And agreed - can you confirm that from unpowered directly into the BIOS still exhibits the behaviour? (i.e: don't let Windows touch the hardware)

Comment: @Attie Yes, I can confirm that. I will update my question reflecting that.

Comment: I saw similar case with a new CMOS battery. Motherboard was draining out the battery and the voltage was lower than expected. Check that you have 3V on the battery cage contacts.